# root of binary matrix

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, roots

There is a square matrix A defined over the field GF(2). It means there are zeros and ones in its cells, xor stands for element summation, logical and - for multiplication.

Is there any way to find all matrices B (over GF(2)): B^n = A?

Comment: The problem of finding all the roots in a finite group is sort of unstructured. I doubt a very useful generic algorithm is there. Once you work out the exponent of the group, you can start looking for some tricks, but I would only attempt to answer this question for a specific pair of $A$ and $n$. The tricks I could easily think of will heavily depend on that. For example, if $n$ is coprime to the order of $GL_m(GF(2))$ ($m$ the size of the matrices), then the answer will be unique, and a power of $A$.